# como faço para chamar uma rota com react sem depender da tag ,<Link to='/'>

Tags: react, react-router, react-router-dom

quero fazer meu app ir para uma determinada rota assim que eu chamar uma função especifica

```
function logar(u,p){
const body={
    user:u,
    pass:p
}
const init = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    };
fetch(url_api,init)
.then(data =>{
    if(!data.ok){
        alert('usuarios ou senha incorretos Code:001');
    }
    return data.json();
})


  .then(resposta=>{
        console.log(resposta);
        if(resposta.auth){
            localStorage.setItem('token',resposta.token);
           console.log('logado!');
        
        }
    }).catch(e=>{
        console.log('erro: '+e);
    })
}
```

**routes.js**

```
 import React from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Routes,
    Route
  } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from '../pages/home/home';
import Login from "../pages/login/login";
import Cadastrar from "../pages/cadastrar/cadastrar";
import Erro404 from "../pages/404/404";
import AddHorario from "../pages/criarHorario/newHorario";

function Rotas(){
    return(
        <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>} />
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
          <Route exact path="/cadastrar" element={<Cadastrar/>} />
          <Route exact path="/criar/horario" element={<AddHorario/>} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Erro404/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
        )}
export default Rotas;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para react-router-dom use o [`usehistory`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory), na versão 5 deve importar assim:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

Se estiver usando outras funções ao mesmo tempo, é só separar por vírgula (as quebras de linha são opcionais):

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  useLocation,
  useHistory 
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Então com useHistory após uma requisição com fetch ou um setTimeout ou qualquer callback, faça isso:

```
let history = useHistory();

fetch(....).then(data =>{
    history.push("/home");
})
```

Na versão 6 do react-router-dom use o [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate), mais ou menos assim:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

...

let navigate = useNavigate();

fetch(....).then(data =>{
    navigate("/home");
})
```

Se desejar substituir a rota atual, "sem paginar", então use `, { replace: true }`, assim:

```
navigate("/home", { replace: true });
```

Comment: na versão 6 da erro sempre:

Comment: @AmigoDroid qual erro?

Comment: esse erro que mostrei na resposta que adecionei

Comment: vou comentar o erro

Comment: @AmigoDroid não adicione no campo resposta algo que não é uma resposta a pergunta, de qualquer forma, não coloque o `let navigate = useNavigate();` dentro da função "logar", ele deve estar no escopo do método principal que vai usa-lo.

Comment: Line 41:17:  React Hook "useNavigate" is called in function "logar" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: ok vou atualizar aqui

Comment: Line 5:14:  React Hook "useNavigate" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: ainda com  erro, não intende o que esse codigo quer qui eu faça

Comment: acabei de colocar meu arquivo de rotas, talvez tenha algo errado nele

Comment: @AmigoDroid provavelmente você colocou o import no outro script e está tentando acessar o método em outro script, não tem como saber o que você fez direito, recomendo que leia [mcve] para ver como fornecer uma exemplo que ajude os outros a ajuda-lo ;)

Comment: @AmigoDroid Outro detalhe, pela mensagem *React component names must start with an uppercase letter.* significa que seu componente (se é que tem um componente) começou com o nome da função com letra minuscula, e as regras definem que tem que começar com letra maiuscula, defina logar() para Logar(). Deve ter mais erros, mas não tenho como analisar da forma que a pergunta se encontra.